# removing fields with numbers in linq to entity query

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following linq to entity query

```
Dim results = (From t In ctx.events
               Where t.date >= dStartDate.Date And t.date <= dEndDate.Date
               Order By t.time
               Select New With {
                   t.symbol,
                   t.date, t.time,
                   t.description,
                   t.domestic_call_num,
                   t.web_url}).ToList()
```

I want to limit the return results so that i only get results where t.symbol doesn't contain a number in its value.
I'm not certain how to accomplish this as the methodsI have tried don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array of strings with digits, and simply check if symbol contains any digit. Here is C# solution (works with EF)

```
var digits = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".Split();
var result = from t in ctx.events
             where t.date >= dStartDate.Date && 
                   t.date <= dEndDate.Date &&
                   !digits.Any(d => t.symbol.Contains(d))
             orderby t.time
             select new {
               t.symbol, t.date, 
               t.time, t.description,
               t.domestic_call_num,
               t.web_url };
```

---

I believe in VB code will look like:

```
Dim digits = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".Split()
Dim result = From t In ctx.events 
             Where t.[date] >= dStartDate.[Date] AndAlso t.[date] <= dEndDate.[Date] AndAlso Not digits.Any(Function(d) t.symbol.Contains(d))
             Order By t.timeNew From { _
                t.symbol, _
                t.[date], _
                t.time, _
                t.description, _
                t.domestic_call_num, _
                t.web_url _
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

> doesn't contain a number in its value

Assuming you mean:

1. `symbol` is a string.
2. Contains a *digit* character.

Then, if this were being done on the client) a simple regex would work:

```
Dim results = (From t In ctx.events
               Where t.date >= dStartDate.Date And t.date <= dEndDate.Date
               Where Not Regex.IsMatch(t.symbol, "\d")
               Order By t.time
               Select New With {
                 t.symbol,
                 t.date, t.time,
                 t.description,
                 t.domestic_call_num,
                 t.web_url
              }).ToList()
```

However that is unlikely (a EF provider could implement regular expressions) to work client side. Accepting a specific set of digits (eg. just the Arabic digits of western languages) makes the problem much easier: see the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16913572/67392).

A more general solution on the server would likely be dependent on the details of functions (or Entity-SQL) from the provider you are using. Unless such a significant proportion of rows would be filtered out that it makes a difference (more data to be transferred) then a hybrid solution is possible. Do as much filtering on the server as can be done easily there, and perform the rest locally (if I've got the VB syntax right):

```
Dim results = (from s in (
                 From t In ctx.events
                 Where t.date >= dStartDate.Date And t.date <= dEndDate.Date
                 Order By t.time
                 Select New With {
                   t.symbol,
                   t.date, t.time,
                   t.description,
                   t.domestic_call_num,
                   t.web_url
                 }).ToEnumerable()
               Where Not Regex.IsMatch(s.symbol, "\d")
               Select s
              ).ToList()
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Oops: no, that would require performing things client side. However I'm not sure—without knowledge of the provider—that can be avoided (needs more than a SQL `LIKE`).

Comment: yes, the regex is not working in the query. I am using mySQL as the provider

Comment: Expanded the answer more fully.